# How to use gather and aligned with multiple labels?

Tags: align, gather, aligned

1. The code below gives me ?? when referencing the equations. How do i fix it ?
2. How do I get (1a,1b) for the first equation if possible?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
f: A \to B, g: B \to C \label{eq:1} \\
\begin{aligned}
f(a) &= \ldots \label{eq:2} \\
g(b) &= \ldots \label{eq:3}
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}

\ref{eq:1} \ref{eq:2} \ref{eq:3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: as your output shows, rows of aligned to not get separate numbers, so can not have separate labels

Comment: You can achieve your second point by wrapping environment ``subequations`` from ``amsmath`` around the respective ``gather``, ``align`` or ``equation`` environments.
Or did you  mean to ask for numbering these three lines into "(1)", "(1a)" and "(1b)" ?

Comment: thank you, i meant that i would like to split (1) into (1a,1b) since there are 2 equations in line 1.

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. It seems that you should make more clear what you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

It is then better to use `align`. If you do not want the first equation to be aligned with the others, then it is possible to use `\mathclap` from `mathtools` package

**Off-topic:** cross referencing is better handled with `cleveref` package

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{align}
        & \mathclap{f: A \to B, g: B \to C} \label{eq:1}
        \\
        f(a) &= \ldots \label{eq:2}
        \\
        g(b) &= \ldots \label{eq:3}
    \end{align}
    
    \cref{eq:1,eq:2,eq:3}
    
    \ref{eq:1} \ref{eq:2} \ref{eq:3}
    
\end{document}
```